# Extending selection with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get BeautifulSoup to do the following.

I have HTML files which I wish to modify. I am interested in two tags in particular, one which I will call TagA is

```
<div class ="A">...</div>
```

and one which I will call TagB

```
<p class = "B">...</p>
```

Both tags occur independently throughout the HTML and may themselves contain other tags and be nested inside other tags. 
I want to place a marker tag around every TagA whenever it is **not immediately followed** by TagB so that

```
<p class="A"">...</p> becomes <marker><p class="A">...</p></marker>
```

But when TagA **is followed immediately** by TagB, I want the marker Tag to surround them both

so that

```
<p class="A">...</p><div class="B">...</div> 
becomes 
<marker><p class="A">...</p><div class="B">...</div></marker>
```

I can see how to select TagA and enclose it with the marker tag, but when it is followed by TagB I do not know if or how the BeautiulSoup 'selection' can be extended to include the NextSibling.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

beautifulSoup **does** have a "next sibling" function.  find all tags of class A and use a.next_sibling to check if it is b.

look at the docs:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways

Comment: Thanks - but how do I select the two tags together in order to put them both inside my marker tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was going about this the wrong way by trying to extend the 'selection' from one tag to the following. Instead I found the following code which insets the outer 'Marker' tag and then inserts the A and B tags does the trick. 
I am pretty new to Python so would appreciate advice regarding improvements or snags with the following.

```
def isTagB(tag):
#If tag is <p class = "B"> return true
#if not - or tag is just a string return false
    try:
        return tag.name == 'p'#has_key('p') and tag.has_key('B')
    except:
        return False

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class = "A"><p><i>more content</i></p></div><div class = "A"><p><i>hello content</i></p></div><p class="B">da <i>de</i> da </p><div class = "fred">not content</div>""")


for TagA in soup.find_all("div", "A"):
    Marker = soup.new_tag('Marker')
    nexttag = TagA.next_sibling
    #skipover white space
    while str(nexttag).isspace():
        nexttag = nexttag.next_sibling
    if isTagB(nexttag):
        TagA.replaceWith(Marker)   #Put it where the A element is
        Marker.insert(1,TagA)
        Marker.insert(2,nexttag)
    else:
        #print("FALSE",nexttag)
        TagA.replaceWith(Marker)   #Put it where the A element is
        Marker.insert(1,TagA)
print (soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.urlopen("http://ursite.com") #gives html response
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

all_div = soup.findAll("div",attrs={}) #use attrs as dict for attribute parsing 
#exa- attrs={'class':"class","id":"1234"}

single_div = all_div[0]

#to find p tag inside single_div
p_tag_obj = single_div.find("p")
```

you can use obj.findNext(), obj.findAllNext(), obj.findALLPrevious(), obj.findPrevious(),
to get attribute you can use obj.get("href"), obj.get("title") etc.